# how to get id of entity using nhibernate createcriteria

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

Newbie Alert
I am trying to check if an entity exists in the database, if it does i want to update it else create a new entity. But CreateCriteria use always returns an entity with no id? Any ideas why? I am using fluent nhibernate for manual mapping i.e use of ClassMap;

Base class -hold only the Id public property

> public abstract class EntityBase : IEquatable
>       {
>           public virtual int Id { get; set; }

```
    public virtual bool Equals(EntityBase obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (GetType() != obj.GetType()) return false;
        return obj.Id == Id;
    }
}
```

MAPPING;

> ```
> public class ProjectNameMap: ClassMap<ProjectName>
> {
>     public ProjectNameMap()
>     {
>         Table("dbo.TABLENAME");
>         Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
>         Map(x => x.PROJECT_NAME).Not.Nullable();
>         Map(x => x.PROJECT_DESCRIPTION);
>     }
> }
> ```

Getting back the entity;

> ```
>     public static T GetEntityByRestrictions<T>(String propertyName, String propertyValue)
>                 where T:EntityBase
>     {
>         using (var session = SessionManager.CreateSessionFactory().OpenSession())
>         {
>             using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
>             {
>                 var entity=  session.CreateCriteria<T>(propertyValue)
>                                     .Add(Restrictions.Eq(propertyName, propertyValue))
>                                     .UniqueResult<T>();
>                 return entity;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Two silly steps i tried (dont laugh)
1. Silly step i tried was to manually set the Id =52 matching existing database entry and i keep on getting a primary key violation on project name as the database expects unique project name.

1. More silly steps (i can hear laughter) modified mapping file to include Map(x=>x.Id).Update().Insert() and this lead to INSERT_IDENTITY set to OFF (or somethin).

So whats the best way to get an entity with Id and update afterwards,is there something wrong with my CreateCriteria?

Comment: Have you looked at the logs to see what queries it's actually running against the database?

Comment: You really don't want to be creating a new session factory every time you want an entity.

Answer (score 0):

I believe calling the **Merge** method on the session will do exactly what you want.

Just put in the entity you want to update/insert as an argument and it will update the properties if the entity already exists or persist the new instance if it does not.  This way you don't need the **CreateCriteria** and your solution will be a lot simpler.